# How do I send results from C# app to a Django web service?

Tags: c#, django

I have a C# console app that stores its results locally in a CSV file. The size of this results file varies from a few bytes to around 0.5MB.

I would like to add the ability for the C# app to also send the results to a Django web app; the Django app would store the results in a database. I'm not sure how to go about getting the data from the C# app to the Django web app. What C#/Django libraries and technologies should I be looking at for each end? Are there any resources on the web that describe how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) to create an API for your django app, and then `POST` to it from your C# application.